Samsung A52 stuck in KG STATUS: CHECKING (00)
after I'm install new firmware on Samsung A52 from: https://samfw.com in Download Mode i got:
CURREMT BINARY: Samsung Official
FRP LOCK: OFF
OEM LOCK: ON(L)
KG STATUS: CHECKING (00)
WARRANTY VOID: 0x)
QUALCOMM SECURYTYBOOT: ENABLE
RP SWREV: etc
SECURE DOWNLOAD: ENABLE
HDM STATUS: NONE

KG STATUS stuck on CHECKING could it be a firmware fault?

I got SIM
I'm waiting long time
Before Installation i got status: COMPLETED

